# What is bucket used in hashing, with reference to a memory location?

Tags: java, hash, collections, hashmap, hashcode

In HashMap, or anywhere where hashing technique is used, hashcode method is called on the object, to calculate a hash that is used to find the bucket where the Entry object is stored.

The value returned by the hascode() method is not a memory location. What exactly then is the concept of bucket with reference to a memory location?

If it is a single memory location then how is it possible to hold a linked-list of Map entries there?

I have found similar questions in stack, but none clearly explains what a bucket really is. Please help me clear the concept of bucket.

Comment: @EJP I did not say that there are memory locations in Java. I was refering to the memory location where all values are stored

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Hashing, hashcode() value decides the bucket index. Many objects may have same hashcode() value. In such case, all such objects will be mapped to same bucket.

Theoretically bucket can be imagined as a container for all such objects. It can be implemented in various ways. It is implemented as a simple linked list in "HashMap" implementation. It means, bucket is implemented as a linked list. We can imagine that each bucket is a linked list.

For example, if there are 3 objects (A,B,C) in a bucket, bucket can be visualized as linked list A->B->C->null

Answer (score 2):

Bucket in a hashtable is nothing but an array index (in most cases).

Your hash function will always return you the index of the array where you need to place your object (or do any operation per se as per requirements). So to understand how memory is managed, you need to understand how arrays are allocated memory.

They are given contiguous memory locations to make sure dynamic access to any index works perfectly.

**What is hash table returns the same index**

Then you can make that index point to a linked-list or another array to store further values.

When accessing these values you can simply access the desired index from the hash function in constant time, and if that index holds multiple values, you can iterate over those values assuming that index points to a linked list.

Linked-list in this case will be at a separate location. The starting address of that location will be pointed to by that array index.

Comment: Thankyou. I was asked this question in a interview where I was confused with the bucket being a memory location. Now cleared